# Mysql Adding date/time stamp to file produced, or other method of automated file naming to keep resulting files unique

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
   SELECT 
'"Part #"',
'"Manu"',
'"Qty"',
'"partdesc"',
'"Rohs status"'
UNION all 
(
SELECT partno, manuf, qtyleft, partdesc, stfifo.ROHScompliance
    FROM stmaster, stfifo
    WHERE stmaster.internal = stfifo.internal AND stfifo.warehouse = 'MAIN'

AND manuf != 'aaaa' 
AND manuf <>'bbbb' 
AND manuf <>'cccc' 

AND stmaster.partno <>'yyyyyyyyy' 
AND stmaster.partno <>'xxxxxxxx' 
AND QTY >0
GROUP BY partno, manuf
ORDER BY partno ASC
INTO OUTFILE
    'D:/Reporting/abc - 19.03.15.xls' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  ' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY ''
```

How do I make it so that the resulting file includes today's date as determined by a NOW() function? CONCAT() functions seem useless as the file is within a UNION all() function. At the moment I cannot run this query more than once without deleting the .xls file first. Any other workarounds are greatly welcomed. Thanks in advance

Comment: what if you add file names using script. You can declare a date variable in shell script such as dto=`date +%d'_'%b'_'%Y'_'%H_%M_%S`  and then add this variable in your file name to make it unique..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use shell script for this.

First write a script to do so.. a sample is as below

## !/bin/bash

> dto=`date +%d'_'%b'_'%Y'_'%H_%M_%S`
> mysql -uroot -p dbname -e " select * from table_name into outfile 'file1_$dto' "

This will always give you unique names against your files.

Hope it helps.